# Need help to deploy CAS 4.2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am deploying CAS 4.2 on Tomcat 8.0, but I always get a failure. I am following [this guide](https://jasig.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html), to integrate LDAP authorization.
There is a step adding entry
`schema/spring-ext.xsd` into `xsi:schemalocation`.

But, actually, the url of `xsd` does not exist and the server failed to read the `xsd` during startup.

If I delete the entry the server would fail due to the error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
 Line 64 in XML document from ServletContext resource
 [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 64; columnNumber: 45;
 cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
 declaration can be found for element 'ldaptive:ad-authenticator'
```

Does any one succeed to deploy CAS 4.2.1?